# Обновление одних колонок DataGrid, при изменении других(DataGridComboBoxColumn)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Есть колонка датагрида, вида:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="1" Width="auto" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding DayType_notify}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" CellStyle="{StaticResource DayType}">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.DayTypes}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.DayTypes}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

При изменении её значения, надо пересчитывать другие колонки:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WDCount}" Header="РД" IsReadOnly="True"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding WHCount}" Header="РЧ"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Вот так выглядит DayType_notify:

```
public DayType DayType_notify
{
    get
    {
        return DayType;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != DayType)
        {
            DayType = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DayType");
            OnPropertyChanged("DayType_notify");
            CalculateWorkDaysAndHours();
        }
    }
}
```

Значения WDCount и WHCount пересчитываются, но DataGrid не обновляется. Пробовал и в датагриде обрабатывать событие CurrentCellChanged, хоть это и не очень красиво для MVVM:

```
private void DG_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = (CalendarViewModel)DataContext;
    if ((bool)Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new VmCalcWdWhCanExecute(viewModel.CalcWdWh.CanExecute)))
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new VmCalcWdWhExecute(viewModel.CalcWdWh.Execute));
}
```

Но обновление происходит с "запозданием", т.е. тыкаешь в другие строчки, и только тогда обновляет.
В чем может быть проблема, и как это решить?

Код CalculateWorkDaysAndHours:

```
/// <summary>
/// Рассчитывает кол-во часов и рабочих дней в графике
/// </summary>
/// <param name="timetable">график</param>
/// <param name="messages">сюда добавляются сообщения об ошибках</param>
public static void CalculateWorkDaysAndHours(dynamic timetable, ObservableCollection<string> messages = null)
{
    try
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = timetable.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        int wdCount = 0;
        int whCount = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(property.Name))
                continue;
            if (!property.Name.StartsWith("d"))
                continue;
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                bool isWorkDay = false;
                var propVal = property.GetValue(timetable, null);
                if (propVal == null)
                    continue;
                string strVal = propVal.ToString();

                foreach (var dtWorkDay in PutlModel.DaytypesWorkDays) if (strVal == dtWorkDay) isWorkDay = true;

                if (isWorkDay)
                {
                    wdCount++;
                    whCount = whCount + int.Parse(strVal);
                }
            }
        }
        if (timetable.WDCount == null || timetable.WDCount != wdCount)
            timetable.WDCount = wdCount;
        if (timetable.WHCount == null || timetable.WHCount != whCount)
            timetable.WHCount = whCount;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        if (messages != null)
            messages.Add("Метод CalculateWorkDaysAndHours, неверный параметр(dynamic");
    }
}
```

WDCount и WHCount обычные сгенерированные EF6 свойства в таблице Timetable:

```
public int WDCount { get; set; }
public int WHCount { get; set; }
```

Comment: Покажите свойства `WDCount` и `WHCount` и код метода `CalculateWorkDaysAndHours`

Comment: Добавил свойства и код метода в изначальный пост

Comment: `WDCount и WHCount обычные сгенерированные EF6 свойства в таблице` — поэтому и не обновляется, откуда GUI узнает что их пора обновить?

Comment: Да, я об этом подумал, когда просматривал код CalculateWorkDaysAndHours, думал что там сообщается об обновлении. Добавил в свойство DayType_notify -  OnPropertyChanged("WDCount"); OnPropertyChanged("WHCount"); , и по прежнему обновление не происходит

Comment: И не сработает, потому что `WDCount` не лежит в этой VM, оно принадлежит другой сущности. По хорошему вы должны сделать отдельную VM с этими свойствами и реализовать в ней INPC, привязываться напрямую к модели выйдет только если модель неизменяема, либо сама реализует INPC

Answer (score 0):

с "запозданием" потому что так работает CurrentCellChanged, можете попробовать использовать CurrentCellChanging

Comment: Так же, обновляется с запозданием. Есть предположение, что связано с DataGridComboBoxColumn